# Why isn't my jQuery Dialog opening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I was given some code to add to an email application I'm building so that when someone clicks the 'preview' button, a dialog will pop up and display the text as it would appear in the email. I've only been programming with JavaScript for about a week now and I've done my best to research how the jQuery Dialog box works, but for the life of me I just cannot get it to open when the button is clicked.

These are the two functions I was given:

```
<script>
$("#loadPreviewDiv").dialog({
    autoOpen : false,
    resizable : true,
    height : 600, //adjust accordingly
    width : 600, //adjust accordingly
    modal : true,
    buttons : {
        close : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },

});

function loadPreviewView() {
    document.getElementById('loadPreviewDiv').innerHTML = 'htmlBody.innerHTML';
    $("#loadPreviewDiv").dialog("open");
} </script>
```

And here is my button that is supposed to open the dialog:

```
<button type="button" onClick="loadPreviewView()">Preview</button>
```

I do know that the loadPreviewView() function is being called, however the dialog box just isn't popping up. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you loading the jquery and jquery ui libraries?

Comment: Are there any errors on the JavaScript console in your browser's debugging tools?

Comment: Yes, I have <script> statements for both libraries in the head section of the document.

Comment: I don't see `$(document).ready()`, have to initialized the dialog inside `$(document).ready()`? if not, jQuery might not have been initialized when it was called.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#loadPreviewDiv").click(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        title: "Dialog box",
        height: 300,
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
        },
        buttons: { "close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } } 
    });
 });
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/xkRUx/2/